# input string is not in the correct format - double type

Tags: vb.net

I have two text boxes that have double value and i need to calculate the yield. I have changed the code to use Double.Parse now and i am still getting the same result. Attached image shows the error and my run time value. x and y place holder variables have my values. What am i missing here?

[image]

```
Dim FinalProdWt as Double = 0.0
Dim TargetWt as Double = 0.0
Double.Parse(txtFinalProdWt.Text, FinalProdWt)
```

I am getting "input string was not in correct format" exception. I have been using vb.net after a long time (13 years) and i can't replicate the issue in sample C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `Double.Parse` like it was `Double.TryParse`.  That code should be:

```
FinalProductWt = Double.Parse(txtFinalProductWt.Text)
```

You must have `Option Strict Off` or you'd have been warned that your second argument was not the correct type.  Turn `Option Strict On` and leave it `On`.

I was actually thinking when I first looked at the code that you really should be calling `TryParse` rather than `Parse`, so maybe your mistake was actually calling the wrong method rather than passing the wrong arguments.

Comment: I can't change any thing on this form other than the 3 methods that i need to fix so can't put option strict on. I had tryparse in my mind. Thanks for the pointer, I'll check and update in the morning.